# Ember gives 404 after page refresh 404 apache on localhost

Tags: apache, ember.js

This probably has to do with not using rails or hosting in couchapp, but I'd like to solve this problem without involving another layer of code.

I'm writing an Ember app, and when I refresh the browser on any route except the index (home) route I get a 404. Getting to routes only works when it's done through Ember code, such as `{{#linkTo}}`s or `transitionTo`s.

Apache version: `Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with one (or all) of your model hooks.  Since everything after the # doesn't get sent back to the server, so any link-to or transition wouldn't make any difference,

`server/cow` is the same to the server as `server/cow#/comments/3/posts`.

Aka, you might have been passing models down to each nested resource lower using a link-to, but when it reloads that route, the param in the url is passed to the model hook to resolve the model.

As was pointed out below in the comments, if you aren't using the hash tag (aka using location:history or location:none) you need to use some form of url rewrite at the root of your ember application so your url.  Be aware that if you choose one of those options you are limiting the functionality of your application to modern browsers (http://caniuse.com/history).

Comment: Before I do a jsbin, I'll say this: I've added the `location: 'history'` to my `App.router` which was supposed to get rid of the hash (I thought it was annoying). I'm not familiar with this nuance of Ember though! Can you point me in the direction of any documentation on this?

Comment: And what I mean by "this nuance of Ember" is it's apparent relationship with the server. This bug actually makes a lot of sense to me, since when manual url request is done (through a refresh or when it is manually typed) that request is sent to the SERVER, and Ember never even sees it. Does Ember have code that accounts for that? That's documentation I've never seen and would like to see.

Comment: Ahh, since you aren't using the # the entire url is being sent back to the server.  At that point it sounds like your server doesn't know how to handle the url.  You'll need to find a method of ignoring the request after the rootUrl of your ember application (I think this could be accomplished in nginx pretty simple)

Comment: [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845048/client-side-javascript-app-url-routing-with-no-hash-tag) had the exact same problem, but I didn't find his answer because I didn't realize this had to do with not having the hashtag! Edit your answer to point to that or something, and I'll be glad to accept it!

Comment: And also [the apache mod_rewrite page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) detailing that actual api.

Comment: Good to know, additionally depending on who your target audience is you'll want to make sure that you are fine with the location:'history' setting (see above).