# Emberjs remove the hashtag from the URL

Tags: ember.js

Its a quick question but I was wondering if it was possible to remove the # symbole from the URL in emberjs ? I know its not possible in many framwork, but I was curious to know about ember.

And if yes, how is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Client-side Javascript app - url routing with no hash tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845048/client-side-javascript-app-url-routing-with-no-hash-tag)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right removing the hash would defeat the whole point of using ember.js as other urls would point to other html pages and when you use ember.js you download only one page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can see the relevant part in the [Ember Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/)

Keep in mind that doing so would mean that you need to configure your server to serve the ember app for all the possible routes that you can accept

it is also possible for you to make it so that the page that's served with such a route would have the added benefit of a normal emberless page in it's noscript tag as a form of SEO optimization (trying to reason why you would do this)

more can be found in the [API Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_historylocation) 
revealing the nice option of using `location:auto` instead of `location:history` providing a more backwards compatible solution

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: I found your answer recently and referred to the API docs.  The docs did not specify where to place this bit of code?  I put it into my router.js file and it broke my app. Is there a specific place to put this code?

Comment: no router.js is the correct location to add this.

keep in mind why you are adding `location:'auto'` tho, as it will invoke `location:'histroy'` in modern browsers without your backend serving the correct routes, will result in getting wrong 404 pages served to you (should you visit the page through the address bar eg. `localhost:3000/posts` would expect a posts page to be served, in contrary to `localhost:3000/#posts` which serves index.html then ember calls the posts handlebars template.

just to check that using this doesn't break anything turn it to `location:'hash'` which is the default.