# All routes doesn't works after deploying ember app

Tags: ember.js

I am creating one ember app. The app is working fine while running on development server (using ember serve), but when i build my app using `ember build -prod` and deploy it on my server which is apache, just index route works and nothing else.

This is understandable as only index path is physical but i am not finding any way to get this done.

Is there any documentation on build process which can enable all routes?

Comment: Maybe this is useful https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-ember-cli-and-apache/7755/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something EmberJS can fix through the build process. You need to change your server's configuration.

Apache's *mod_dir* has a "Fallback resource" directive you need to activate for your website since the JavaScript router URLs are not pointing to actual files or folders.

Add this directive in the VirtualHost entry:

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16554242/574015)